# RDP connection gives black screen to users from different forest

Tags: active-directory, azure, remote-desktop, trust-relationship

I run a virtual Windows Server 2016 machine on Microsoft Azure. This machine is joined to a forest A. Forest A is in a bidirectional trust relationship with forest B.

If I RDP to this machine with a user from forest B, I *am* able to establish a session, but I'm met with a black screen. I'm able to CTRL+ALT+DEL, but nothing else. In the `C:\Users\` folder, I can observe that there *is* a folder called `C:\Users\user_from_forest_b`, but it only has `AppData` and `ntuser.dat`. Any other user has a fully built user folder with `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Pictures` etc.

Everything works fine if I connect with a user from forest A.

I've read certain other tips out there, with the most popular ones being to disable bitmap caching and simply hitting Ctrl+alt+end and then cancel, but neither option works. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There might be something wrong with DNS configuration.
Make sure the server in Azure has correct DNS servers set, and Forest A DNS servers have conditional forwarders configured for Forest B (and vice versa)

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko Thank you for that suggestion. However, I don't think this is the case. It's clear that the credentials are successfully authenticated. If I enter non-valid credentials, I get an error message. If I enter valid credentials, I'm met with a black screen.